# How to force alarm clock to have the screen always on

Tags: wiring, battery

I have an alarm clock, that has batteries and a power cord as a power source.
[image]
[image]
If it's using batteries, it turns the screen off after a few seconds. If it's plugged in, then the screen is on constantly.

Is it possible to modify it, so that is stays on, when using batteries?
[image]

Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about DIY Home Improvement.

Comment: @brhans fair enough. Is there another SE site where this would fit?

Comment: Not that I know of. And before anyone suggests 'Electrical Engineering', modification of consumer electronics is off topic there unless you already have at least a partial schematic of the circuit.

Comment: Note that 1) to be able to pull this off, you need to have sufficient skills in reverse-engineering the schematic of the circuit from the board, and 2) there's a very good reason for shutting off the display when on batteries, because otherwise the clock is going to drain the batteries in a matter of hours, perhaps a day if you're really lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the pcb, to make it believe the DC input jack is plugged in while it is powered by batteries, I'd recommend bridging the "+" side of the batteries with the "+" pin of the DC input jack.

Diodes on the PCB hint about the polarity: it should work if you solder a wire as shown by the green arrow. Still use a multimeter to check for polarity, of course.

[image]

Bonus: you can use a switch instead of just a jumper to turn the display on and off.

Safety note: with the display on constantly, battery will run out faster so the alarm will not work in the morning.

You could mess with display intensity to make it less bright, but from the "SDA" silkscreen print on the pcb, the display looks like it's controlled via I2C bus which is a digital protocol, so whatever controls the LED brightness is probably a resistor next to a chip on the display PCB and not on the PCB included in the question.

Comment: Yes, trick it, OP does not ask about battery life...

Comment: @SolarMike The MCU most likely senses DC input jack voltage through R15 (bottom right), but I'm not going to advise someone of unknown soldering skills to mess with a tiny SMD resistor. The big solder blobs are a much easier target.

Comment: Too many people "down vote " questions that they do not understand just to hide their inability to understanding of a question. Remember, there a lot of smart people monitoring this and other sites.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this answer but I think it doesn't serve OP well. Yes, it answers the question as asked, but there's a significant probability that OP will ruin a perfectly good device while attempting the modification (we have no reason to believe they have any experience soldering, this is going to be lead-free solder and both the DC jack and the battery contact are going to sink a lot of heat, so it's not going to be trivial to solder for newbies). And all that just to experimentally confirm that the resulting battery life makes the modification completely pointless.

Comment: @TooTea, he asks how to modify it and posts a picture of a PCB, I don't think it is too far-fetched to conclude he's asking how to modify that pcb. No lethal voltages are involved, there are protection diodes everywhere (way too many of them, in fact), and it's a clock not granny's oxygen life support machine. Methinks you worry too much.

Comment: Sure, no doubt they're asking how to modify that PCB, but the question reeks of an X-Y problem. I'm not talking about danger to life, but about needlessly destroying the device attempting what this answer presents as a simple modification. It only takes an accidental solder bridge to make it useless, and such a thing can happen very easily if OP has zero experience with electronics (and it's likely they do, otherwise they wouldn't have asked this question this way).

Comment: I think at some point we should just let the OP have the information and deal with it appropriately. If the OP ruins the clock, we’re not responsible. If they succeed, even with hiccups and some on-the-fly learning, perhaps even better. It’s a fairly nice question since contrarily to popular belief, it can actually be answered accurately from the provided photo alone. That’s kinda rare when it comes to reverse engineering. Let’s cherish this one, folks!

Comment: I downvoted because the question is blatantly off-topic for this stack. We should not encourage such questions by answering them.

Answer (score 0):

If that clock time is of that much importance to you, why not buy a back-up battery similar to those used for a desk top computer. When the power goes off the back-up battery will power the clock for an extended period of time. A 650VA back-up can be had for about $50.00.